# CompletableFuture is not getting executed. If I use the ExecutorService pool it works as expected but not with the common ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, concurrent.futures

I am trying to run the following class its getting terminated without executing the CompletableFuture.

```
public class ThenApplyExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    CompletableFuture<Student> studentCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        try {

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 3;
    })// If I put executorservice created n commented above, programme work as expected.
            .thenApply(i -> {

                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Inside first then apply");
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("First then apply is finished");
                return ++i;
            })
            .thenApply(i -> {
                System.out.println("Inside 2nd then apply");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Inside 2nd then apply stopped");

                return i++;
            })
            .thenApply(i -> {
                System.out.println("Inside 3nd then apply");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Inside 3nd then apply stopped");
                return "The i is ::: " + i;
            })
            .thenApply(s -> Student.builder().id(1).name(s).address("Some address").build());
    System.out.println("Executing..");
    System.out.println("Executing..");
    System.out.println("Executing..");
    System.out.println("Executing..");
    System.out.println("Executing..");

    //es.shutdown();
}
}
```

**Output I am getting is**

```
Executing..
Executing..
Executing..
Executing..
Executing..
```

**Whereas expected output is**

```
Executing..
Executing..
Executing..
Executing..
Executing..
Inside first then apply
Inside first then apply
Inside first then apply
Inside first then apply
First then apply is finished
Inside 2nd then apply
Inside 2nd then apply stopped
Inside 3nd then apply
Inside 3nd then apply stopped
```

> **Note :** In the above programme, I am not using studentCompletableFuture.get(). I dont want to use it since it blocks the code.

If I add **studentCompletableFuture.get()** at the very end of the programme, it works as expected or if I add the **executorservice** in the supplyAsync 2nd argument(check comment in programme), it works again as expected.

**My question is why it is terminating when programme uses the default ForkJoin common pool?**

Comment: Didn't analyze your code in depth but this most likely has to due with the fact the threads in the `ForkJoinPool` are _daemon_ threads whereas the threads in your `ExecutorService` are not.

Comment: @Slaw how will it make the difference. Whether its daemon thread or executorservice pool thread, it should execute the async calls

Comment: Because your main thread simply launches the async tasks and exits. Since the `ForkJoinPool` threads are daemon threads they don't keep the JVM alive. In other words, the only non-daemon thread (the main thread) exits and therefore the JVM exits before your async code completes. This is why calling `get()` makes it work; it causes the main thread to wait (thus keeping it alive).

Comment: @Slaw That makes sense. Is there any other elegant way to make this run while using `ForkJoinPool` common pool threads and not using studentCompletableFuture.get(). In java 9, there is a way by using studentCompletableFuture.completeOnTimeout or by using studentCompletableFuture.orTimeout(). But, how to do in java8?

Comment: @Slaw I just checked ForkJoinPool common threads are not daemon thread by using  `System.out.println("The thread is :: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());`
On 2nd thought, whether its daemon thread or not, these threads have the task to complete then why these are letting the main thread to exit.

Comment: When the main thread exits the `main` method it has completed its work and dies. The other threads have no effect on this unless the main thread is told to wait for them to complete before continuing. Remember, `supplyAsync` calls the `Supplier` on a _different_ thread than the caller and the caller thread returns immediately.

Answer (score 26):

**TL;DR:** The `ForkJoinPool` uses *daemon* threads, whereas the `ExecutorService` is using *non-daemon* threads. The latter keep the JVM alive; the former do not. Also, the main thread is a *non-daemon* thread and when you block it waiting for the `CompletableFuture` to complete it remains alive (thus keeping the JVM alive).

---

## Daemon vs Non-Daemon Threads

A [platform thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#platform-threads) in Java can either be a *daemon* thread or a *non-daemon* thread. A *daemon* thread does not keep the JVM alive. This behavior is documented:

> Platform threads are designated daemon or non-daemon threads. When the Java virtual machine starts up, there is usually one non-daemon thread (the thread that typically calls the application's `main` method). The [shutdown sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#shutdown) begins when all started non-daemon threads have terminated.

In other words, it doesn't matter how many *daemon* threads are alive or what they're doing, if there are no *non-daemon* threads alive then the JVM will exit.

###### Virtual threads

As a quick aside, [virtual threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#virtual-threads) were added in Java 21 (preview feature in Java 19 and 20). A virtual thread is always a daemon thread.

> Virtual threads are daemon threads and so do not prevent the [shutdown sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#shutdown) from beginning.

### "Main" Thread

As noted in the above documentation, there is typically a single *non-daemon* thread when a JVM starts. And this thread is usually the one that invokes the main method. Unless other *non-daemon* threads are started (and stay alive) the JVM will exit once the main thread terminates.

### ForkJoinPool

A `ForkJoinPool` uses *daemon* threads, at least by default. This behavior is also [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html):

> All worker threads are initialized with [`Thread.isDaemon()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isDaemon()) set `true`.

<sup>*– Last sentence, second paragraph of class Javadoc*</sup>

This means work submitted to the `ForkJoinPool` will not keep the JVM alive.

### ExecutorService

Most of the `ExecutorService` instances returned by the factory methods in `Executors` are configured to use *non-daemon* threads by default. Unfortunately this default behavior does not seem to be documented. If you want the pool to use *daemon* threads, however, then you can supply a `ThreadFactory`.

An exception to this default behavior are the `#newWorkStealingPool(...)` methods. They return a `ForkJoinPool` (an implementation detail).

---

## The Behavior of Your Code

The differences in behavior between the different versions of your code can be explained by the use of *non-daemon* threads versus *daemon* threads.

### No Waiting for Task to Complete

Your original code looks like this (vastly simplified):

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(
        () -> {
          System.out.println("Sleeping...");
          Thread.sleep(2000L); // try-catch omitted for brevity
          System.out.println("Done!");
        });
  }
}
```

That code is launching an asynchronous task via [`CompletableFuture#runAsync(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable)), which:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` after it runs the given action.

As you can see the task is passed to the common `ForkJoinPool`. That means the task is being executed by a *daemon* thread. You also do not wait for the task to complete. The `runAsync` call submits the task and returns immediately. Then the main thread simply exits the main method and terminates. Since the only *non-daemon* thread has terminated the JVM also exits—before the asynchronous task had time to complete.

### Waiting for Task to Complete

When you modify your code to wait on the future:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> {
              System.out.println("Sleeping...");
              Thread.sleep(2000L); // try-catch omitted for brevity
              System.out.println("Done!");
            })
        .get(); // wait for future to complete
  }
}
```

You are now blocking the main thread in the `get()` call. Said thread remains blocked until it's interrupted or the task completes (normally or exceptionally). This means a *non-daemon* thread remains alive until the task completes, thus the JVM stays alive.

### Using Custom ExecutorService

Modifying the original code again, this time to use a custom `ExecutorService`:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(
        () -> {
          System.out.println("Sleeping...");
          Thread.sleep(2000L); // try-catch omitted for brevity
          System.out.println("Done!");
        },
        executor); // use custom ExecutorService
    executor.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Now instead of using the common `ForkJoinPool` the task is submitted to the given `ExecutorService`. In this case that thread pool is using *non-daemon* threads. And that means those threads will keep the JVM alive. This is true even though the main thread is allowed to exit the main method and terminate before the task completes.

The fact *non-daemon* threads are being used is why it's important to call `#shutdown()`. Without that the threads are allowed to persist and keep the JVM alive "indefinitely". Though it's possible a "cached thread pool", specifically, may allow all threads to eventually die from being idle too long.

Note calling `#shutdown()` still allows all already-submitted tasks to complete.

---

## Addressing Comments

In one of your comments you ask:

> Is there any other elegant way to make this run while using ForkJoinPool common pool threads and not using studentCompletableFuture.get().

I'm not sure what you would consider more "elegant", but you could use the `#join()` method instead. That method behaves very similarly to `#get()` without throwing checked exceptions. But be warned: A call to `#join()` **cannot be interrupted**. There's also no timeout overload (though you can combine it with `orTimeout` / `completeOnTimeout` in Java 9+).

In another one of your comments you mention:

> I just checked ForkJoinPool common threads are not daemon thread by using `System.out.println("The thread is :: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());`

I don't know why or how you're seeing that, but the following:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> {
              Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
              System.out.printf("Thread[name=%s, daemon=%s]%n", t.getName(), t.isDaemon());
            })
        .join();
  }
}
```

Gives this output:

```
Thread[name=ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, daemon=true]
```

Comment: 1+. a tiny addendum about waiting if you do not mind. `ExecutorService` and `CompletableFuture` with a custom `ForkJoinPool` [work very different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643737/how-does-forkjoinpoolawaitquiescence-actually-work/67924031#67924031) if you plan to `await` for task completions.

Comment: Additional note, if you want to wait for *all* tasks in ForkJoinPool to complete use `awaitQuiescence()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054261/5267751