# Why CompletableFuture.runAsync is not executed?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I consider that main thread must end after sub thread. However, below code shows the process finished before print the "async end". What is the reason? Can anybody explain?

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("async start");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("async end");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        System.out.println("main end");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is executed, you just aren't waiting for the result.

The Javadoc of [`CompleteableFuture.runAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-) says:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` after it runs the given action.

The Javadoc of [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) says:

> Any program that relies on asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination should invoke `commonPool().awaitQuiescence()`, before exit.

So, invoke that.