# Why does CompletableFuture not run the task with runAsync?

Tags: java, completable-future

I want to make a test program with `CompletableFuture`. I have a class with 2 functions:

```
public class FutureTextData {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private  CompletableFuture<Void> futureForText;

    public void getCharInText(String text){
        futureForText = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length()-3; i++) {
                map.compute(text.substring(i+1),(key,value) -> value+=1);
                map.compute(text.substring(i+2),(key,value) -> value+=1);
                map.compute(text.substring(i+3),(key,value) -> value+=1);
            }
            for(Map.Entry<String ,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
                if(entry.getKey().length()==3)
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey());

            }

        });
    }

    public void recordCharInText(String outPutFile){
        /*try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            File file = new File(outPutFile);

            try(BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))){
                for(Map.Entry<String ,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
                    bf.write(entry.getKey() +"<----->" + entry.getValue());

                }

            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In `getCharInText()`, I want to count the number of certain substrings in the text, and in `recordCharInText()` I want to record the current state of the Map.

And when I run the program:

```
FutureTextData futureTextData = new FutureTextData();
futureTextData.getCharInText(result);
futureTextData.recordCharInText("outFile.txt");
```

Then everything just completes without errors and everything. i.e. map is not written to the file, and `getCharInText()` is not even executed.

Can you tell me what the error is?

Comment: The second future may run before the first one is finished.

Comment: @dan1st if i just run ```futureTextData.getCharInText(result);```  the program just ends

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CompletableFuture is not getting executed. If I use the ExecutorService pool its work as expected but not with the default forkJoin common pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879659/completablefuture-is-not-getting-executed-if-i-use-the-executorservice-pool-its)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ForkJoinPool` `CommonPool` which runs your tasks will shut down when the program exits:

```java
    /**
     * Returns the common pool instance. This pool is statically
     * constructed; its run state is unaffected by attempts to {@link
     * #shutdown} or {@link #shutdownNow}. However this pool and any
     * ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program
     * {@link System#exit}.  Any program that relies on asynchronous
     * task processing to complete before program termination should
     * invoke {@code commonPool().}{@link #awaitQuiescence awaitQuiescence},
     * before exit.
     *
     * @return the common pool instance
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static ForkJoinPool commonPool() {
        // assert common != null : "static init error";
        return common;
    }
```

If I modify your code to add `awaitQuiescence` and log the execution of the tasks I get:

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class FutureTextData {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public  CompletableFuture<Void> futureForText;

    public void getCharInText(String text){
        futureForText = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("Running first task");
            map.put("foo", 1);
        });
    }

    public void recordCharInText(String outPutFile){
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("Running second task");

            File file = new File(outPutFile);

            try(BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))){
                for(Map.Entry<String ,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
                    bf.write(entry.getKey() +"<----->" + entry.getValue());

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        FutureTextData futureTextData = new FutureTextData();
        futureTextData.getCharInText("xyz");
        futureTextData.recordCharInText("outFile.txt");
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
Running first task
Running second task

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ok, but if I add ```Thread.sleep(10000);```  in 2 functions, the program still does nothing

Comment: I also added a simple print to future For Text and nothing was printed to the console

Comment: Because your program exits before the futures are executed: "However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program exit" Try adding the sleep at the end of `main`.

Comment: Of course you might still get an empty file, because your two tasks are running concurrently

Comment: added ```Thread.sleep(20000);``` at the end of main, launched only 1 counting function and still did not go inside it

Comment: That's odd. See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You intend to compute the map and write the result to a file:

```java
FutureTextData futureTextData = new FutureTextData();
futureTextData.getCharInText(result); // populate map
futureTextData.recordCharInText("outFile.txt"); // write values to a file
```

- The current code executes the two operations (compute `map` and write to file) on two different threads concurrently. But, you want to write the `map` to file only when the CF in `getCharInText` has completed.
- The CFs, by default, use `ForkJoinPool CommonPool`, which terminates when your program exits. The `main` thread doesn't wait for the threads in `getCharInText` and `recordCharInText` to complete. It calls the methods and returns immediately.

Here's how the code should look like:

```java
public class FutureTextData {

    public CompletableFuture<Map<String, Integer>> getCharInText(String text) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            var map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 3; i++) {
                // For this case, javadoc suggests to use merge instead of compute
                
               /* map.compute(text.substring(i+1),(key,value) -> value+=1);
                map.compute(text.substring(i+2),(key,value) -> value+=1);
                map.compute(text.substring(i+3),(key,value) -> value+=1);*/
                
                map.merge(text.substring(i + 1), 1, Integer::sum);
                map.merge(text.substring(i + 2), 1, Integer::sum);
                map.merge(text.substring(i + 3), 1, Integer::sum);
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().length() == 3)
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            }

            return map;
        });
    }

    public void recordCharInText(String outPutFile, Map<String, Integer> map) {
       // write to file logic
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FutureTextData futureTextData = new FutureTextData();
        futureTextData.getCharInText("soeerrt text")
                       // supply the map to next execution step
                      .thenAccept(map -> futureTextData.recordCharInText("outFile.txt", map));

        // wait for the tasks to finish
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Note:

- I moved `map` inside `getCharInText`. Always try to avoid mutation inside lambdas.
- The lambdas for the CFs can be a method. Lambdas should be at most 2 lines

Comment: thanks for helping and corrections!